# matplotlib update installation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

im new to the python world , i been trying to plot using matplotlib . I get it to work but it still gives me errors about updating it , how can i update it? here's the code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#                      0
img = cv2.imread('bryan.jpg' ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
#IMREAD_COLOR = 1
#IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1
cv2.imshow('image' , img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation= 'bicubic' ) 
plt.plot([50,100],[80,10], 'c' ,linewidth=5)

plt.show()
```

plus the error:You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
http://matplotlib.sf.net/_static/matplotlibrc or from the matplotlib source
distribution

Comment: If matplotlib tells you to update your matplotlibrc file, it's probably a good idea to do so. 

You will find all the details on http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html